# Can't convert JObject values to custom object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

No matter what I try, I can't convert json to custom object. I know the issue is not the SerializableVector2 because I was able to populate it with System.Text.Json but I need to use Newtonsoft.Json.

```
JObject j = JObject.Load(reader);
string tObj = j["Transform"].ToString();
Transform transform = j["Transform"].ToObject<Transform>();
```

tObj returns

```
{
  "Position": {
    "X": 200.0,
    "Y": 100.0
  },
  "Scale": {
    "X": 256.0,
    "Y": 256.0
  }
}
```

However, transform is always empty.

Here is my Transform class

```
public class Transform
{
    private SerializableVector2 position;
    private SerializableVector2 scale;

    public SerializableVector2 Position
    {
        get => position;
        set => position = value;
    }

    public SerializableVector2 Scale
    {
        get => scale;
        set => scale = value;
    }

    public Transform()
    {
        Init(SerializableVector2.Zero, SerializableVector2.Zero);
    }

    public Transform(SerializableVector2 position)
    {
        Init(position, SerializableVector2.Zero);
    }

    public Transform(SerializableVector2 position, SerializableVector2 scale)
    {
        Init(position, scale);
    }
    
    public void Init(SerializableVector2 position, SerializableVector2 scale)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public Transform Copy() => new(position, scale);

    public void Copy(Transform to)
    {
        to.position = position;
        to.scale = scale;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Transform))
            return false;

        Transform t = (Transform)obj;
        
        return t.position.Equals(position) && t.scale.Equals(scale);
    }
}
```

And for good measure here is SerializableVector2

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableVector2
{
    private float x;
    private float y;

    [JsonConstructor]
    public SerializableVector2(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public SerializableVector2(Vector2 vector)
    {
        x = vector.X;
        y = vector.Y;
    }

    public float X => x;
    public float Y => y;

    public Vector2 ToVector() => new(x, y);
    public static SerializableVector2 Zero => new SerializableVector2(Vector2.Zero);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the question and had all the code in front of me, I found the issue.

I just needed to add the JsonConstructor attribute to my Transform class.

```
[JsonConstructor]
public Transform(SerializableVector2 position, SerializableVector2 scale)
{
    Init(position, scale);
}
```